# Error en envío de mail en laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estoy intentando enviar un correo electronico desde un programa en laravel, siguiendo un video tutorial realicé lo que dictaban en el.

En el archivo config/mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => ['address' => 'email@gmail.com', 'name' => 'name'],
'encryption' => env('ssl'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Y en el archivo .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Y por último en el programa tengo esto para el envío del correo

```
Mail::send('emails.contact',$plan,function($msj) use ($plan)
{
    $msj->to($plan[0]['correoParaPlanTrabajoAlerta']);
    $msj->subject($plan[0]['correoAsuntoPlanTrabajoAlerta']);
    $msj->attach(public_path().'/plantrabajo.html');
});
```

Pero consigo el siguiente error:

```
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""
```

He leído que puede ser que no haya validado la cuenta de gmail pero no se cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné reemplanzado `'encryption' => env('ssl'),` por `'encryption' => 'ssl',`

Answer (score 0):

Realmente deberías tener en el archivo config/mail.php:

```
...
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION'),
...
```

para que lea el parámetro del archivo .env